# Light a LED with a Raspberry Pi when a call is made to a web service (Flask, python)

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, webserver, cron

Each time a call is made on a web service on our backend, I want to blink a LED.

It's working, but only for few hours, after that, it just stops working.

Each time we post on this URL (http://IP_ADRESS:PORT/scan), our LED is blinking.

I'm wondering why, after a certain amount of time it stops working..

Here is the code called when a POST is done:

```
@app.route('/scan', methods = ['POST'])
def scan():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    try:
            LED.rainbow()        
    finally:
           print("Scanned")
    return 'Scanned!!!'
```

The LED.rainbow() code can be found [here](https://github.com/prynt/Claudie/blob/master/LED.py).
The code of the whole project can be found [here](https://github.com/prynt/Claudie/).

When it stops working, I connect via ssh on the raspberry Pi and I do:

```
python
>>> import app
>>> app.scan()
```

And  this make the LED blinking!! I don't understand why it's working with ssh and not via the http POST.

At the beginning, I thought the Flask server was crashed, but when I try to call it via CURL, everything is fine:

```
$ http -f POST http://IP_ADDRESS:PORT/scan
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Length: 13
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 02 Jun 2016 20:11:02 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/0.11.9 Python/2.7.9

Scanned!!!
```

Here is how I launch my Flask server on the raspberry Pi:

```
$ sudo crontab -e
# Add this line at the end of the file
@reboot python /home/pi/Desktop/Claudie/app.py &
```

What am I missing?

Any help is appreciate!

Thanks!

Comment: We're missing some code around the `try` I think. also can you try a `time http -f POST http://IP_ADDRESS:PORT/scan` when it works (as there's some sleep it may take some time) and the same command when is stopped working ? To see if the execution take the same amount of time, or if something beaks early and the 'sleep's are not executed.

Comment: Thanks @JulienPalard! I just edit my code, I removed the finally block because it's just a log, just put it back. Thanks, I'll monitor that with time!!

Comment: Don't forget to tell us even if you find it ;-)

Comment: I will ! Do you have the same problem? Or just by curiosity?

Comment: Neither, for future others finding this question on SO ;-) They'll need the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug!

The problem is in  the `rainbow()` function.

This function is called severals time, and at a certain time, it stops working.

Here is what the function do:

```
def rainbow():
    RED, GREEN, BLUE = initializeGPIO() # setup the GPIO, outputs, and PWM

    # Light the LED

    GPIO.cleanup()
```

I noticed that calling this function in a loop (without the web server) stops working.

So I removed the `cleanup()` and `initializeGPIO()`, and now everything is working perfectly :)  I don't really know why initializing the GPIO (or cleanup) makes the LED stop working, if someone  knows, I'll be happy to read it!